# Parsing a Tab Separated File

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to TSV from IMDB:

```
$hutter             Battle of the Sexes (2017)  (as $hutter Boy)  [Bobby Riggs Fan]  <10>
                    NVTION: The Star Nation Rapumentary (2016)  (as $hutter Boy)  [Himself]  <1>
                    Secret in Their Eyes (2015)  (uncredited)  [2002 Dodger Fan]
                    Steve Jobs (2015)  (uncredited)  [1988 Opera House Patron]
                    Straight Outta Compton (2015)  (uncredited)  [Club Patron/Dopeman]



$lim, Bee Moe       Fatherhood 101 (2013)  (as Brandon Moore)  [Himself - President, Passages]
                    For Thy Love 2 (2009)  [Thug 1]
                    Night of the Jackals (2009) (V)  [Trooth]
                    "Idle Talk" (2013)  (as Brandon Moore)  [Himself]
                    "Idle Times" (2012) {(#1.1)}  (as Brandon Moore)  [Detective Ryan Turner]
```

[image]

As you can some lines start with a tab and some do not. I want a map with the actor's name as a key and a list of movies as the value. Between the actor's name is one or more tabs to until the movie listing.

My code:

```
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            Matcher matcher = headerPattern.matcher(line);
            boolean headerMatchFound = matcher.matches();

            if (headerMatchFound) {
                Logger.getLogger(ActorListParser.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Header for actor list found");

                String newline;

                reader.readLine();

                while ((newline = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] fullLine = null;

                    String actor;
                    String title;

                    Pattern startsWithTab = Pattern.compile("^\t.*");
                    Matcher tab = startsWithTab.matcher(newline);
                    boolean tabStartMatcher = tab.matches();

                    if (!tabStartMatcher) {

                        fullLine = newline.split("\t.*");

                   System.out.println("Actor: " + fullLine[0] +
                          "Movie: " + fullLine[1]);

                   }//this line will have code to match lines that start with tabs.
                }
          } 

        }
```

The way I've done this only works for a few lines before I get and `arrayoutofbounds` exception. How can I parse the lines and split them into 2 strings at max if they have one or more tabs?

Comment: Don't post data listings as screenshots.  Copy/Paste the data and indent 4 spaces for fixed-width formatting.

Comment: Is the data listing issue actually a SO rule? Copy pasting the data is a mess and takes a long to fix.

Comment: It's a very strong recommendation.  You only need to show a few lines of data, enough to communicate your question, not a full screen.  Images should be reserved only for things that are truly images.  If it's text it belongs in the post as text.

Comment: I'm going to keep it as is until there is a rule that states otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Since you did not provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcv I can only guess that your `split` regex is bad, i.e., the `.*` matches till the end of the String, and you end up with just a single element array being returned. Hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to print array element 1.

Comment: The code is there.

Comment: There is code, yes, but it's incomplete. I cannot just copy and paste it into an editor and run it. `line`, `reader`, and `headerPattern` are not defined, and I'd need to figure out what logging system you use. Add a `main` method, add all the input file handling, add the `import`s. I am too lazy to do that. If you can't be bothered to make it easy to help you, I cannot be bothered to try to help.

Answer (score 1):

There are subtleties in parsing tab/comma-delimited data files having to do with quoting and escaping.

To save yourself a lot of work, frustration and headaches you really should consider using one of the existing CSV parsing libaries such as OpenCSV or Apache Commons CSV.

Posted as an answer instead of a comment because the OP has not stated a reason for reinventing the wheel and there are some tasks that really have been "solved" once and for all.

Comment: I generally agree with using a CSV library, but this format doesn't even look CSVish enough to me.